# Notation when integrating with respect to a measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have seen the following three notations and was wondering if they were all equivalent:

Over $(S, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$,

$\int_S f \, d\mu= \; \int_S f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_S f(x) \mu(dx)$

to denote the act of integrating over a measure?
Moreover, while (at least in my course), we assume this to be the Lebesgue integral over the bounds of S which can, should it Riemann integrable over these same bounds, be rexpressed as a Riemann integral - is this true in the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the notations are all equivalent, the last one (I believe) being more prominent in probability theory. In the real line, you have that if a function is Riemann integrable, then it is Lebesgue integrable and the values are the same. Meaning $$\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x = \int_{[a,b]} f(x)\,{\rm d}\mathfrak{m}(x).$$For this reason, people often use the left-hand side above to also denote *Lebesgue* integrals. For more details, you can check the end of Section 3 of Chapter 2 in Folland's Real Analysis book.